# PIP não funciona no virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Após ativar o virtutalenv o pip não funciona, recebo o seguinte erro

```
wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog$ source bin/activate
(Blog) wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog$ pip freeze
bash: /home/wilker/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog/bin/pip: "/home/wilker/Documentos/Git/Curso: bad interpreter: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

Porém fora dele funciona normalmente.Já removi o pip,e o virtualenv e os reinstalei.

Tentei novamente e recebi o mesmo erro.

```
wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django$ virtualenv Blog
New python executable in /home/wilker/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django$ cd Blog/
wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog$ source bin/activate
(Blog) wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog$ pip
bash: /home/wilker/Documentos/Git/Curso Django/Blog/bin/pip: "/home/wilker/Documentos/Git/Curso: bad interpreter: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era o espaço no nome de diretório em "Curso Django".

> `wilker@debian:~/Documentos/Git/Curso Django$ virtualenv Blog`

Aparentemente o caminho absoluto de um ambiente virtual não deve conter espaços, pois os scripts gerados para o virtualenv não lidam bem com os espaços. Como dito em:

> Create your virtualenv environment within a path without spaces. This
>   is why it is happening:
>
> When you create an environment, it sets up a bin directory. In that bin directory are all the executables relating to the environment. Some are scripts. As you may know, hashbangs are used to tell thesystem what interpreter to use to run the script. You may see this at the top of scripts often:
>
> `#!/usr/bin/env python`
>
> If the script is at `/tmp/test.py`, that tells the system to run this command to execute the script:
>
> `/usr/bin/env python /tmp/test.py`
>
> In your case, virtualenv is creating
>   scripts like this:
>
> `#!/tmp/oh no/bin/python`
>
> When the system tries to execute that, it will try to execute the command `/tmp/oh` with the arguments `no/bin/python` and `/tmp/test.py`. `/tmp/oh` does not exist, so it fails.

Retirado de:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911003/cant-install-via-pip-with-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar o comando `python -m pip install nome_do_pacote`